# как прокручивать картинку?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

у меня картинка отображается в picturebox
мне нужно её в низ и вверх прокручивать. как это сделать?

с начало думал поместить picturebox в другой компонент
и этот другой компонент сделать прокручиваемым
т.е. прокручивая этот другой компонент, прокручивается и моя picturebox
вверх \ низ

вот так.

p.s. на форме form1 у меня имеются другие компоненты типо: label, button

Answer (score 1):

Поместите `PictureBox` в контейнер, например `Panel`.

У этой `Panel` есть свойство `AutoScroll`, которому вы можете присвоить `true` и должны появится полосы прокрутки.

Comment: побывал такой вариант. не появляется ничего.

Comment: @j0siit если картинка маленькая - и не появится. Задайте размер PictureBox соответствующий размеру картинки, если она большая, и все появится.